# Plot of $f(z) = iz^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \sqrt{3} < |z| < 2, -\frac{\pi}{4} < arg(z) < 0 \}$ and $f(z) = iz^2$. I need to draw $f(D)$.

So, I know that $D$ looks like this

[image]

Then what happens is that I take a square of each complex number $z$. Using de Moivre formula

$$
z^2 = |z|^2\left(\cos 2\phi + i\sin 2\phi \right)
$$
So the angle is doubled and the radius is squared. That should result in

[image]

Now the tricky part for me is multiplying $z^2$ by $i$. I know that $i= e^{i\pi/2}$, so it $iz^2$ should be $z^2$ rotated by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians, so $90^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. As you have observed, this map sends $re^{i\theta} \mapsto r^2e^{i(2\theta + \pi/2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. And more generally, multiplication by a unit modulus complex number $e^{i\theta}$ is a rotation by angle $\theta$. So $f(D)$ is the corresponding quarter annulus in the first quadrant.